# Parsing apache tomcat accesslog with java

Tags: java, parsing, logging

What's the best way to parse an apache accesslog file with using java?

Would it be using a stringtokenizer or are there any 3rd part libraries that are specially made for parsing apache logfiles ?

Comment: You can try log parser: http://javatechworld.blogspot.com/2011/08/apache-http-access-log-parser.html to parse access logs. It parses the logs and generates a corresponding CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 3rd part libraries specialized in parsing tomcat log files. Still there is a lot you can do yourself:

1. Define the characteristics of your log file and the necessary valve format
2. Define the actions you need to process (access log, struts actions etc.)
3. Read in the lines of the log file and split them (i.e. `oneLine.split(" ", 0);`)
4. Store the components you need in a database if you want. A DB will give you a lot of freedom.

And you are ready to go!

Rotatable logfiles are easier to work with. You will have many, but smaller. 
Filter out any unnecessary lines.

Parsing depends on the pattern you use in server.xml.
 A sophisticated solution would read the valve pattern from the server.xml file and know how to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, StringTokenizer is too stupid for anything, and a third party library may be an overkill for something as simple as this. I'd write a simple regex, provided it's not crucial and runs under my control. There are 280k matches for http://www.google.com/search?q=Parsing+apache+tomcat+access+log, and the first two seem to be free libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Inside this [github project](https://github.com/raimonbosch/accesslog.hadoop) you will find a class called `LogParser` that is covering some accesslog formats. Furthermore is doing all the process with Hadoop which mean that you'll be able analyze in parallel big amounts of accesslog with commodity hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JMeter's `TCLogParser` [[javadocs](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/accesslog/TCLogParser.html) | [source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jakarta/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/accesslog/TCLogParser.java)]. It's actually meant to be used from within JMeter, but you can check out the source and change it for your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Web Log Analyser]http://code.google.com/p/web-log-analyzer/

Answer (score 0):

Please evaluate this Java library which is already widely used (for example it is included in Apache Drill) for parsing Apache HTTPD accesslog files and which also support Nginx accesslog files.

Two main reasons for using this (besides that I wrote it):

- Supports almost all custom formats in addition to the default LogFormat specifications.
- Supports getting deeper fields than just the top level. So if you need a specific cookie value or a specific query string parameter you can get that and all encoding is handled.

https://github.com/nielsbasjes/logparser